# Render A specific V-If inside of a list with Vue based on Api response

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I ran into an issue that I know how to solve pretty easily, but I don't really know how to handle this the "vue way" or in a declarative way that is. I usually would just use traditional DOM manipulation in this case and since that is what I am so used to, I'm having a bit of a hard time trying to do this the way it should be done in vue.

The problem is in this array of two products, one product only has one in stock, so if it is added to the cart it shouldn't be able to be added again. Now since we loop over the array, I have an error that can be conditionally shown. In the below code,  each item will have an error message on it since the `v-if` condition will evaluate to true.

What would be good way to handle this declaratively, rather than in the traditional way? Usually I would just pass in `$event`, get the current target and `insertAdjacentHTML`. I am confused how this would work declaratively since we need to handle the v-if logic after a request comes back from an api.

```js
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div v-for="(product, index) in products" class="product__wrapper" style="position: relative; background: #ccc; margin: 24px;">
        <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
        <button @click="addToCart(product.id)">add to cart</button>
        <div v-if="lastItemIsInCart" class="error">All items are currently in your cart</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="module">
    Vue.createApp({
      name: 'test-app',
      data() {
        return {
          products: [],
          lastItemIsInCart: null
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        fetch('/products')
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            this.products = data.products
          })
      },
      methods: {
        addToCart(productId) {

          fetch(`/cart/add/${productId}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
               // unique to this api
               if (data.status !== 200) {
                 throw new Error(data.description)
               }
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.error(err.message) // all xyz products are in your cart
             // set this.lastItemIsInCart to true for a specific product so that v-if doesn't become true for each item in the list 
            })

        }
      }
    }).mount('#app')
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Do you mean that an error message should display under the only product which is out of stock?

Comment: Yes, when you add a product to the cart you have to wait for the response to know if it was added or not, if not then the `v-if` should activate only under the problematic item. This would be easy using $event and insertAdjacentHTML but I am struggling to know how to set this up in the declarative vue way

Comment: Check my answer below, I got it to work fairly well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got close to what I am looking for, this could be improved because of the setTimeout but here is a good way to do it:

```js
 <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div v-for="(product, index) in products" class="product__wrapper" style="position: relative; background: #ccc; margin: 24px;">
        <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
        <button @click="addToCart(product.id)">add to cart</button>
        <div v-if="addToCartError && addToCartError.id === product.id" class="error">{{ addToCartError.message }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="module">
    Vue.createApp({
      name: 'test-app',
      data() {
        return {
          products: [],
          addToCartError: null,
          timeout_id: undefined
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        fetch('/products')
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            this.products = data.products
          })
      },
      methods: {
        addToCart(productId) {

          fetch(`/cart/add/${productId}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
               // unique to this api
               if (data.status !== 200) {
                 throw new Error(data.description)
               }
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.error(err.message) // all xyz products are in your cart
              this.addToCartError = {
                message: err.message,
                id: productId
              }

              if (this.timeout_id) {
                clearTimeout(this.timeout_id)
                this.timeout_id = undefined
              }

              this.timeout_id = setTimeout(() => {
                this.addToCartError = null
              }, 4000)
            })

        }
      }
    }).mount('#app')
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making the variable `lastItemIsInCart` a simple `true/false` for all products, I would consider making this an object containing the success/error state for each product fetch.

Something like:

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(product, index) in products" class="product__wrapper" style="position: relative; background: #ccc; margin: 24px;">
    <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
    <button @click="addToCart(product.id)">add to cart</button>
    <div v-if="product.id in productState" class="error">{{ productState[product.id] }}</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

```
data() {
  return {
    productState: {},
  }
},
methods: {
  addToCart(productId) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if quantity == 1 {
        this.productState[productID] = 'All items are currently in your cart'
      }
    }, 2000)
  }
}
```

You then have the option to easily extend the functionality by updating the state for a product, which in turn will show if the id is in `productState`.

(Note: while a simple `in` tets is fine for a `v-if` if this is ever more complex it would be worth moving out into a computed property).

Comment: I gave a basic example but the way it works is you hit an endpoint `fetch('cart/add.js')` and that api sends back an error message, 'all xx are in your cart'. I can hit `fetch('cart.js')` and get a list of products back, but the api doesn't work in this manner that you can check quantities

Comment: When I send a fetch post request with a product Id, it tells me if their software internally added it to the cart or not, based on that general response I need to set a v-if in a manner that would not be true for all instances

Comment: Yes - the if-test is just an example - in your case you would catch the error message and assign it's value to the `productState` object, which would then be displayed under the matching product in the v-for.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, if I catch you correctly, you want to show the error only under the product which is declared as "Already Added" by the API.

so, one way would be that after the API response, you can assign your `lastItemIsInCart` variable with the value of that product's id which is out of stock, and then in the template, you can show the error message only under the product whose id is matched with the `lastItemIsInCart`.

Here is a demo which will display error for product 2 and 3 but allow product 1 to add.

```js
Vue.createApp({
  name: 'test-app',
  data() {
    return {
      lastItemIsInCart: null,
      cartItemsCount: 0,
      products: [
        {
          title: 'Product 1',
          id: 1,
        },
        {
          title: 'Product 2',
          id: 2,
        },
        {
          title: 'Product 3',
          id: 3,
        }
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addToCart(productId) { 
      // Suppose API is returning an error for product 2 and 3 that these items are already added then assign lastItemIsInCart variable with the product's id which is causing the error.
      if([2, 3].includes(productId)) {
        this.lastItemIsInCart = productId
      } else {
        this.cartItemsCount++;
      }
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="app">
      TOTAL PRODUCTS IN CART - {{ cartItemsCount }}
      <div v-for="(product, index) in products" class="product__wrapper" style="position: relative; background: #ccc; margin: 24px;">
        <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
        <button @click="addToCart(product.id)">add to cart</button>
        <div v-if="lastItemIsInCart == product.id" class="error">All items are currently in your cart</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```